# How to prompt a msgbox if connection in the server fails

Tags: excel, vba

I have here the connection string:

```
sConn = "OLEDB;Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=True;Initial Catalog=VQPBOS;Data Source=" & "GHSI" & strcode
```

How do I write an "If statements" to display a Msgbox if the connection fails. Because the user needs to input a "strcode" in order to have a complete server name. And the error message would be

```
Msgbox "Invalid Store Code. Check if the store code you have entered exists in any server"
```

if it cannot connect to that connection string.

I hope you get it. Thank you :)

Comment: Read this answer: [VBA data layer error handling](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4876055/138938)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in thius case you the *ADODB.Connection* object would throw an error on the **Connect** or **Execute** method.

You can trap that error and handle it with the message box.

Here is an example:

```
dim adoCN as new adodb.connection
dim sConn as string

on error goto err_Connection

sConn ="OLEDB;Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=True;Initial Catalog=VQPBOS;Data Source=" & "GHSI" & strcode

with adoCN
    .connectionstring=sconn
    .cursorlocation=aduseclient
    .open
end with
exit sub

err_Connection:
msgbox "The Connection failed to server: " &  "GHSI" & strcode & vbcrlf & vbcrlf & "Please check your connection settings", vbokonly+vbexclamation
```

you can get correct Connection strings either from [Connectionstrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com) or you could create a new **UDL File / Microsoft Data Link**, open it in Notepad, and copy the Connection string

- [MSDN Library: Creating and Configuring Universal Data Link (.udl) Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e38h511e%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)
- [MSDN Library: An easy way to create OLE DB Connection STrings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa140076%28v=office.10%29.aspx)

Comment: @CarissaDeVera: if it's the answer you're looking for, please **accept it** using the green check mark :)