# Get name of current procedure in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

For Error handling, I would like to have the current procedure name pushed into a call stack.

Is there any simple way to accomplish this outside of having to hard-code the name as a local variable for each subroutine?

Comment: look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3792134/get-name-of-current-vba-function

Comment: Have a look at a third party plugin called `MZ-Tools` It's free as far as I can remember and you can set it up for all your modules to have a default error handling. This can include having the name of the module. Therefore when something goes wrong it will give you what you want (This is hard-coded, but the process of coding it is automated)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, no. VBA code has no access to the call stack. A decent technique is here under Advanced Error Handling: https://www.fmsinc.com/tpapers/vbacode/Debug.asp